# Can flash memory be used in place of RAM in microcontroller applications?

Tags: msp430

In my application I'm using a MSP430, however I need to buffer 11kB of data from a UART connection. Obviously the 512B of RAM available is not enough to do this, however the MSP430 has 16kB of flash which would easily do the job.

My basic understanding of flash is that it is used for program code so I am wondering if it is possible to use flash for this purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Not usually.  Flash tends to be slow (and in many implementations, roundabout) to write, often is erasable only in blocks, and has limited lifetime in terms of rewrite cycles.  That said, if your baud rate is low enough and the processor is capable of self flashing, it may be possible to a degree.  More realistically though, if you cannot think up a clever way to solve the problem without more memory, then you've probably chosen the wrong chip.

Comment: In general it's possible, but it's worth adding how often you need to buffer data (endurance may be an issue) and how quickly the data arrived (write speed may be a second issue). There are also differences between devices if you wanted to mention the specific part you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flash is **slow to write to**, only **accessible in blocks** for erasing/writing, on many controllers (not sure about MSP430) **slow to read data from** (in contrast to reading instructions) and flash has **limited write cycles** (order of 100,000 times).

So the answer is: It can probably be done, but you shouldn't want to do it.

Maybe an external I<sup>2</sup>C RAM is an option.

Comment: And if you have a Harvard architecture MCU, may not be mutable in code in the first place.